# Hibernate: batch and non-batch inserts generate the same amount of SQL-queries

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

There is a code sample consisting of two entities with bidirectional mapping.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Post")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();

    public void addComment(Comment comment) {
        comments.add(comment);
    }

    public void removeComment(Comment comment) {
        comments.remove(comment);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Comment")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"id", "post"})
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String review;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Post post;

    public Comment(Post post, String review) {
        this.post = post;
        this.review = review;
    }
}
```

Configuration

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan("jpaDifferent")
public class RootConfig {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RootConfig.class);
        DaoCollections daoCollections = applicationContext.getBean(DaoCollections.class);
        Post post = new Post();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            post.addComment(new Comment(post, "Comment No. " + i));
        }
        daoCollections.savePost(post);
}

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new BasicDataSource();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sfb.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sfb.setPackagesToScan("jpaDifferent");
        sfb.setHibernateProperties(properties());
        return sfb;
    }

    private Properties properties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "10");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.order_inserts", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.order_updates", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data", "true");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Dao

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DaoCollections {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public void savePost(Post post) {
        currentSession().persist(post);
    }
}
```

Hibernate log contains 30 'insert' lines:

```
Hibernate: insert into Post values ( )
Hibernate: insert into Comment (post_id, review) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Comment (post_id, review) values (?, ?)
...........
Hibernate: insert into Comment (post_id, review) values (?, ?)
```

According to Properties in configuration file containing instructions regarding batching, I expect 3 'insert' SQL-queries to be generated. But instead there are 30, one for each 'Comment'. I don't know whether I misunderstood something regarding batching and it is, in fact, not supposed to optimize the number of queries or maybe something is just wrong with configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the Identity Id. Hibernate does not batch when the Id is of type Identity. Use custom or sequences.

Answer (score 0):

The [Batch Updates](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/batchupdate.html) is a way of optimizing SQL execution by sending set of update SQL statements to database as a single unit instead of series of database calls.

Setting a batch size just tells Hibernate that it can batch statements up to `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` in one batch: [ref](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-jdbc-properties)

> A non-zero value enables use of JDBC2 batch updates by Hibernate. e.g. recommended values between 5 and 30

You should not expect less SQL statements generated. It's all about them being send on a single call. More on batching [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/batch/Batching.html).

Comment: > It's all about them being send on a single call
> The time of inserting the data into DB is equal with or without batching, I don't see any difference. Is that how it is supposed to be? Batching clears cache but the speed of query execution is, in fact, the same, isn't it?

Comment: The difference is that in usual operation you get communication like: sql1, execution confirmation 1, sql2, confirmation 2,... And every time your driver is waiting for confirmation from database. With batching many statements are sent and confirmation is done once per batch.

Comment: But according to this, batching should be faster, nevertheless, it is not. Writing 100 lines takes equal time about 15 seconds for either batching or non-batching operations. Maybe Amazon's database just prohibits batching, I don't know...

Comment: 15 seconds is a way to long for 100 insert/update/delete sql statements. You appear to have some other issue.